# C# locate and read binary data from a hybrid text/binary file

Tags: c#, binary

I have a file that contains text data and binary data. This may not be a good idea, but there's nothing I can do about it. The file looks like this:

```
--- CFG data ---
<text cfg data 1>
<text cfg data 2>
...
<text cfg data N>

--- BINARY data ---
<binary data here>
<EOF>
```

I imagine I could read the whole file in binary chunks looking for the binary data header, but I am not sure how to do this smartly in C#. I am also curious if I could open the file as text to locate the binary header, as a way of providing the starting position for a binary read operation.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You could open the file as text with UTF-8 encoding and read it till the position you have the text data. After knowing the position/offset of the binary data, you may open the same file as a FileStream, and seek to the position where the binary data is starting from, then read the binary data till the end as `byte[]`. The tricky part would be to figure out position of binary stream in the file

Comment: You can located the index of where binary starts using following :             byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("filename");
            int index = Array.BinarySearch(data, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });